# How do I make a procedure change the value of a variable argument?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I tried to make a simple procedure that would remove spaces from an inputted string:

```
procedure RemoveSpaces(StringParameter : String);
var
   SpacePosition: Integer;
begin
   SpacePosition := Pos(' ',StringParameter);
   while SpacePos <> 0 do
   begin
      Delete(StringParameter,SpacePos,1);
      SpacePosition := Pos(' ',StringParameter);
   end;
end;
```

but after testing the procedure in the following code:

```
var
   Input : String;
begin
   Readln(Input);
   RemoveSpaces(Input);
   Writeln(Input);
   Readln;
end.
```

it was clear that the Input variable was simply regurgitated out of the procedure as if it was never changed.

I thought it might just be some limit to what I can do with procedures that I had just not yet realized but then I remembered that I had previously made a procedure that takes a StringList parameter and alphabetically sorts the Strings in the StringList and saves the changes to the StringList variable argument:

```
var
   myStringList : TStringList;

implementation

procedure StringListSort(StringList : TStringList);
begin
   //Sort StringList
end;

procedure TFormName.ButtonNameClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   StringListSort(myStringList);
end;
```

Any solution to my problem is welcomed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
procedure RemoveSpaces(StringParameter: string);
```

You are passing the string parameter **by value**. Semantically<sup>1</sup>, a copy is made of the argument you pass, and any modifications made are made to that copy. The caller does not observe the modifications.

You need to pass the parameter **by reference**. When you pass by reference, the procedure operates on the original variable, and not a copy.

In Pascal, and Delphi, [you pass by reference by using the `var` keyword](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Value_and_Variable_Parameters). Change

```
procedure RemoveSpaces(StringParameter: string);
```

to

```
procedure RemoveSpaces(var StringParameter: string);
```

The reason that you observed what appeared to be different behaviour with a `TStringList` parameter is that `TStringList` is a class which is a reference type. That means that given `List: TStringList` then `List` is a reference to the object. For more discussion on the distinction between value and reference types see my answer here: [Why should we use classes rather than records, or vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424868/classes-versus-records/19425207#19425207)

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects#Class_Types) has this to say on the matter:

> A variable of a class type is actually a pointer that references an object. Hence more than one variable can refer to the same object. Like other pointers, class-type variables can hold the value `nil`. But you don't have to explicitly dereference a class-type variable to access the object it points to. For example, `SomeObject.Size := 100` assigns the value `100` to the `Size` property of the object referenced by `SomeObject`; you would not write this as `SomeObject^.Size := 100`.

Here the documentation is rather more explicit about the fact that class type variables are really just pointers.

You can implement your procedure more efficiently and simply by using the RTL function [`StringReplace`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StringReplace):

```
procedure RemoveSpaces(var StringParameter: string);
begin
  StringParameter := StringReplace(StringParameter, ' ', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
end;
```

I would also comment that a function would probably be a better option here. That gives you the flexibility to pass something other than a variable, for instance a literal or a constant. And you can also compose and chain functions more easily.

So this would be

```
function SpacesRemoved(const str: string): string;
begin
  Result := StringReplace(str, ' ', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
end;
```

And then instead of having to write:

```
RemoveSpaces(Input);
Writeln(Input);
```

you can write

```
Writeln(SpacesRemoved(Input));
```

<sup>1</sup> I said semantically because a `string` is a reference type, albeit a special one. The distinction is that if multiple variables refer to the same string object, then when a modification is made, the string is copied to a new object and the modifying variable is given a unique reference. This is known as copy-on-write and has the effect of making the `string` data type behave like a value type.

Comment: My phone made this CW, ah well

Comment: I think you have enough rep you won't really miss these upvotes... ;)

Comment: @DavidM I was more trying to explain why this was CW, in case anyone wondered why I did it. It wisnae me, it wis my phone!

Comment: Granted, @DavidHeffernan is a great developer but ¿Does he code on his phone? Man, that's hardcore.

Comment: @Gixabel Only on the stack, and only for short answers and edits, and only on a phone with an actual keyboard